# How to find the position of the last non-zero value of a decimal in a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following 4 rows and I wish to find the decimal length (aka scale) of that decimal value. Do note that I'm importing all of the decimal data in Excel whose cell is formatted in a "Text" format (hence the trailing zeros even after the decimal values). And I do not want to convert it into decimal. I just need to find the scale of that decimal number.

| Decimal Number | Scale (Formula?) |
| --- | --- |
| 106.520000 | 2 |
| 0.080100 | 4 |
| 15.000010 | 5 |
| 265.000000 | 0 |

Been struggling for a very long time now. I'd appreciate any lead on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have ***tried***,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **B2**

```
=LEN(MID(NUMBERVALUE(A2),FIND(".",A2)+1,255))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=MAX(LEN(-A2)-LEN(INT(A2))-2,0)
```

---

**Note**: I use a decimal comma but it shouldnt matter for you.